# How to change field set while clicking pseudo element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wasted two complete two days to solve this problem. This is a multi-step progress bar form. Here next and the previous section is working properly. But I need to work the progress bar switches also like that. But here used li. I want to li: before as clickable. If we click on it. The fieldset should move by clicking the next and previous button.

```
        <!-- progressbar -->
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".change-btn").click(function() {
        $("#textboxes").toggle();
    });
});

//jQuery time

var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50) + "%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
                'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                'position': 'absolute'
            });
            next_fs.css({
                'left': left,
                'opacity': opacity
            });
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function() {
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        },
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
                'left': left
            });
            previous_fs.css({
                'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                'opacity': opacity
            });
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function() {
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        },
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
    return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="progressbar">
   <li class="active" id="x1">Cart</li>
   <li id="x2">Delivery</li>
   <li id="x3">Payment</li>
   <li id="x4">Confirmation</li>
</ul>
<fieldset id="field1">
   <div class="row" id="m1">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <p>Product</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <p>Price</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <p>Amount</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <p>Cost</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <div class="row" id="m1">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <img src="images/shopping-bag.png">
         <p>New Balance Men's street<br> Backpack
            <br>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <p>$</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <div class="input-group" style="width:100px; margin:auto;">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn  btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="" style="background:transparent;  color:10;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </button>
            </span>
            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="10" min="1" max="100" style="border:none; color:#555; width:50px;">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="" style="background:transparent;  color:10;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <p>$970</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <div class="row" id="m1">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <img src="images/casual-t-shirt-.png">
         <p>Lyle & Scott Men's Shirt
            <span style="padding-left:65px;">Sleeve Camo Pocket</span>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <p>$</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <div class="input-group" style="width:100px; margin:auto;">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="quantity1-left-minus btn  btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="" style="background:transparent;  color:10;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </button>
            </span>
            <input type="text" id="quantity1" name="quantity1" class="form-control input-number" value="10" min="1" max="100" style="border:none; color:#555; width:50px;">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="quantity1-right-plus btn btn-number" data-type="plus" style="background:transparent; color:10;" data-field="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <p>$970</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <div class="row" id="m1">
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="button" name="btn-defualt" class="button5" style="border-radius:20px; background-color:white; padding:5px;  font-size:10px;" value="Continue Shopping" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <p>Total:$1040</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" style="background-color:blue; margin-top:-25px;" value="Shipping" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="inner-padding" id="field1">
   <div class="address" id="m2">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" style="width:auto"><strong>Current Address:</strong></label> Anu Abhraham, Thottingal House, Palliyalil Po, Kuthiran, Thrissur, 6890969
      <hr>
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" style="width:auto"><strong>Shipping Address:</strong></label> Anu Abhraham, Thottingal House, Palliyalil Po, Kuthiran, Thrissur, 6890969
      <hr>
      <!--<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" value="Change">
         <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
         ADD<input type="button" id="change-btn" name="type" value="ADD">
         </a>-->
      <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus change-btn"></i><input type="button" class="change-btn" name="type" id="change-btn" value="Add" style="border:hidden;">
      <div id="textboxes" style="display: none">
         <div class="form-wrapper">
            <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" role="form" method="post">
            <div class="form-inp form-inp1">
               <lable>Name</lable>
               <span class="first-name-space"><input type="text" class="intyp" placeholder="First" aria-label="First name" required ></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-inp form-inp1">
               <span class="last-name-space"><input type="text" class="intyp" placeholder="Last" aria-label="Last name" required ></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-inp">
                     <lable>Email</lable>
                     <input type="email" class="intyp" id="Email" required>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-inp">
                     <lable>Phone</lable>
                     <input type="tel" class="intyp" id="Phone" required>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-inp">
                     <lable>Address</lable>
                     <input type="text" class="intyp" id="address" required>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <!--<div class="from-drop-wrap">
                     <lable>Region</lable>
                     <div class="from-drop">
                                                <select name="cars">
                       <option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">-Select Region-</option>
                       <option value="Australasia">Australasia</option>
                       <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                       <option value="Middle East &amp; Africa">Middle East &amp; Africa</option>
                       <option value="North America">North America</option>
                       <option value="South America">South America</option>
                     </select>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>-->
                  <div class="from-drop-wrap">
                     <lable>Country</lable>
                     <div class="from-drop">
                        <select name="cars" id="Country" required>
                           <option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">-Country-</option>
                           <option value="Australasia">India</option>
                           <option value="Europe">America</option>
                           <option value="Middle East &amp; Africa">UK</option>
                           <option value="North America">North America</option>
                           <option value="South America">South America</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="from-drop-wrap">
                     <lable>City</lable>
                     <div class="from-drop">
                        <select name="cars" id="City" required>
                           <option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">-City-</option>
                           <option value="Australasia">Bangalore</option>
                           <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                           <option value="Middle East &amp; Africa">Middle East &amp; Africa</option>
                           <option value="North America">North America</option>
                           <option value="South America">South America</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <!--<div class="form-inp">
                     <lable>Country</lable>
                                              <input type="text" class="intyp" id="Country" required>
                                          </div>-->
                  <!--<div class="form-inp">
                     <lable>City</lable>
                                              <input type="text" class="intyp" id="City" required>
                                          </div>-->
                  <div class="form-inp">
                     <lable>Zip</lable>
                     <input name="zip" type="text" class="intyp" id="zip" required>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="type" value="Proceed" class="mybu">
               <p align="center">Submit</p>
            </button>
         </div>
         <!--<input type="button" id="change-btn" name="type" value="Proceed">-->
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="del-btn" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" style="margin:30px; text-align:center;" />
   <input type="button" id="del-btn" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Shipping" style="margin:30px; text-align:center;" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset></fieldset>
```

Please check the image. I this progress bar the forward and backward movement is not working while clicking on any of the progress bar button. Like Next amd previous button i want to do the progress bar button also

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.